# Sorting in Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

When I use the Sort "oldest to newest" in the Filter dropdown and I am sitting on, for example Row 400.  After I do the sort my screen resets so I am sitting at the top of the spreadsheet instead of down in Row 400.

is there a setting to change this.  Its an issue for users not compfortable with jumping around a sheet.

Comment: You can type what cell you want to go to in the top, left-hand corner or just press Ctrl+G and type in A400 to go to row 400. You can also use the Ctrl key plus arrows to jump around your sheet better.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there is no such setting available.

If you can use VBA, make a button or a shortcut to launch the sorting action, and then place the cursor where you want it.

Move the cursor to the bottom of the current region:

```
 ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Activate
```

Or an alternative: save the cursor position before the sort and restore it afterwards:

```
Dim SaveCell as Range
(...)
Set SaveCell = ActiveCell
(Sort)
SaveCell.Activate
```